# Inaccurate data from quantmod

Tags: equities, programming, quantmod

For some reason getSymbols is returning inaccurate data for the below symbol. Example for this data in the high column the price went from 35 to 3515 between 2021 feb and 2021 march 16th.

```
d <-  as.data.frame(
     getSymbols(
         paste("USHAMART" , ".NS", sep = ""),
         from ="2000-01-01", 
         periodicity = "weekly" ,
         return.class = 'zoo',
         env = NULL
     )
 )
```

Not sure if this is occurring for other symbols but I doubt it may.

Answer (score 2):

#### The problem lies with Yahoo Finance and not the quantmod package:

By default, **the `quantmod` package sources its data from Yahoo Finance**. If you take a look at the historical data for "USHAMART" on [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/USHAMART.NS/history?p=USHAMART.NS), you will see the same inconsistencies between February 2021 and March 2021 (for a couple of days).

It seems there's only a few inconsistencies in the data. Therefore, **an ad-hoc solution is simply to replace the inconsistent prices with the correct ones, found from an alternative source such as** [TradingView](https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/NSE-USHAMART/) **or similar**.

Comment: Is it possible to get accurate source which quantmod uses?

Comment: It has a source function: `src="yahoo"`, that tells you which source it's downloading from (and by default it is set to Yahoo Finance). See the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantmod/versions/0.4.18/topics/getSymbols).  The only other alternative for OHLC data is Google Finance, which was discontinued from March 2018, so changing the source does not help. A list of sources can be found [here](https://www.quantmod.com/examples/intro/).